# Aggregates for today and the previous day depending on data

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression, window-functions

Having trouble putting together a query to pull the aggregate values of a give timestamp and the timestamp before it. Given the following schema:

```
name TEXT, 
ts TIMESTAMP, 
X NUMERIC, 
Y NUMERIC
```

where there are gaps in the `ts` column due to gaps in data, I'm trying to construct a query to produce

```
name, 
date_trunc('day' q1.ts), 
avg(q1.X), 
sum(q2.Y), 
date_trunc('day', q2.ts), 
avg(q2.X), 
sum(q2.Y)
```

The first half is straightforward:

```
SELECT q1.name, date_trunc('day', q1.ts), avg(q1.X), sum(q1.Y)
FROM data as q1
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

But not sure how to generate the relation to find the "day" before for each row. I'm trying to work an inner join like this:

```
SELECT q1.name, q1.day, q1.avg, q1.sum, q2.day, q2.avg, q2.sum
FROM (
    SELECT name, date_trunc('day', ts) AS day, avg(X) AS avg, sum(Y) as sum
    FROM data
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY 1,2
) q1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, date_trunc('day', ts) AS day, avg(X) AS avg, sum(Y) as sum
    FROM data
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY 1,2
) q2 ON (
    q1.name = q2.name 
    AND  q2.day = q1.day - interval '1 day'
);
```

The problem with this is, it doesn't cover the cases when the next "day" is more than 1 day before the current day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special difficulty here is that you need to number days *after* aggregating rows. You can do this in a single query level with the **window function [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)**, since window functions are applied *after* aggregation by `GROUP BY`.

Also, use a [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to avoid executing the same subquery multiple times:

```
WITH q AS (
    SELECT name, ts::date AS day
          ,avg(x) AS avg_x, sum(y) AS sum_y
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ts::date) AS rn
    FROM   data
    GROUP  BY 1,2
   )
SELECT q1.name, q1.day, q1.avg_x, q1.sum_y
      ,q2.day AS day2, q2.avg_x AS avg_x2, q2.sum_y AS sum_y2
FROM   q      q1
LEFT   JOIN q q2 ON q1.name = q2.name 
                AND q1.rn   = q2.rn + 1
ORDER  BY 1,2;
```

Using the simpler cast to date (`ts::date`) instead of `date_trunc('day', ts)` to get "days".
`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` (as opposed to `[INNER] JOIN`) is instrumental to preserve the corner case of the first row, where there is no previous day.
And `ORDER BY` should be applied to the outer query.

Comment: I can't decide if this is beautiful.. or just black magic. It works perfectly though. If I understand.. we're using the CTE to appropriately gather the aggregate rows, then use the 2nd and 3rd select to merely point to the rows within that CTE that we needed, right? Thanks!

Comment: The CTE acts like a local temporary table. So, yes, you've got that about right - except there is no 3rd select, just a 2nd with a left join.

Comment: right. And `FROM q q1` means from CTE q as q1 and `LEFT JOIN q q1` is from CTE q as q2, correct? Is there a name for that type of syntax? (i.e. haven't found where in the [syntax documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-select.html) I would find / be able to reference this type of code)

Comment: Also - is there a reason you'd want to `ORDER BY` in the CTE as opposed to in the outer query? Assuming you have more than a handful of rows in each name/day group, won't you be sorting roughly the same amount of data?

Comment: @Justin: `FROM q q1` is short for `FROM q AS q1`. `q1` acts as [*table alias*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES). Your link is to the manual of version 8.1, which is *very old*. I linked to the current version. `ORDER BY`: Strictly speaking, only the `ORDER BY` in the outer query is binding. With an `ORDER BY` on a subquery or CTE, even though that usually works, there are *no guarantees* and Postgres is free to return rows how it sees fit (usually the cheapest possible method).

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't crystal clear, but it sounds like you're actually trying to fill gaps while keeping track of leading/lagging rows.

To fill the gaps, look into `generate_series()` and left join it with your table:

```
select d
from generate_series(timestamp '2013-12-01', timestamp '2013-12-31', interval '1 day') d;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html

For previous and next row values, look into `lead()` and `lag()` window functions:

```
select date_trunc('day', ts) as curr_row_day,
       lag(date_trunc('day', ts)) over w as prev_row_day
from data
window w as (order by ts)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @erwinbrandstetter helped get me to the answer but `generate_series()`, `lag()` and `lead()` functions were all tools I haven't seen before and look useful. Thanks!